# Error when running glm with family=gamma

Tags: r, glm

I usually use SAS, so I am not too familiar with R so sorry if this is a basic question.
I have run a model and it is coming up with the following error

```
Error in family() : 0 arguments passed to 'gamma' which requires 1
```

Does anyone know what that means? Have looked everywhere with no success

The code is below:

```
model1<-glm(heartrate ~ age+age*age+sex, family=gamma, data=df)
```

Comment: Try capitalizing Gamma.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, but we have to admit that it's not very clear for newcomers when you have functions named `gamma` and `Gamma`. I think this is a legitimate question that warrants an answer - for future generations.

Comment: Of course it's something really simple, thank you so much!

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Fair point about `gamma` versus `Gamma`. I'll post as an answer and remove my close vote.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here is the difference between `gamma` and `Gamma`.

`Gamma()` is a `family` object, like `binomial`, `gaussian`, etc:

```
class(Gamma())
? Gamma
```

Whereas `gamma()` is a mathematical operation:

```
gamma(1:10)
? gamma
```

You want:

```
model1 <- glm(heartrate ~ age+age*age+sex, family=Gamma, data=df)
```